# Celery can't log string errors in 'utf-8'. UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: django, python-2.7, celery

Sometimes I need to create errors with params in russian language. For example:

```
raise FooError(c_(u'Task %(name)s'), params = {'name': "курочка"})
```

And then I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 868, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 741, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 465, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 329, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I use:

Python 2.7.15rc1;

celery 3.1.19;

django-celery 3.1.17;

Django 1.11.2.

You can reproduce the bug:

```
import logging
from logging import getLogger 
l = getLogger()
handler = logging.FileHandler('/tmp/fh')
l.addHandler(handler)
l.log(50, u'Task 1')
l.log(50, u'Task %(name)s', {'name': "курочка"})
```

I think that there is problem in a Celery. If you open `<your part>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/job.py`, you will be able to see 100-124 lines. There are formed messages in which we will pass the parameters, for example:

```
#: Format string used to log task failure.
error_msg = """\
    Task %(name)s[%(id)s] %(description)s: %(exc)s
"""
```

and it is expected that the data will be string in the English layout (см. function _log_error(<...>)):

```
...
exception, traceback, exc_info, internal, sargs, skwargs = (
    safe_repr(eobj),
    safe_str(einfo.traceback),
    einfo.exc_info,
    einfo.internal,
    safe_repr(self.args),
    safe_repr(self.kwargs),
)
…
```

but **resp** in my Exception returns only str with russian words and all fail. So it is Celery“s problem.

I also know that my LANG=“ru_RU.UTF-8“. I know:
`sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns «ascii»,
and if I write:

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding(«UTF-8»)
```

it will solve my problem and I will have russian message.

But I want to have other solution becouse this decision is not approved by me.

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` ?

Comment: I wrote this line in files other than standard python files and this does not solve the problem.

Comment: `logging.FileHandler(... encoding='utf-8')` ?

Comment: It also doesn't help.

Comment: please post your logging dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this problem!))

Firstly, we edited the file *.../init.d/celeryd*. We added line in the file:

`. /etc/profile.d/lang.sh`.

Secondly, we overrided function `format` in class `logging.Formatter` (file `.../python2.7/logging/__init__.py`). In other words, we created a new class:

```
class FooFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        if isinstance(record.args, dict):
             for v, k  in records.args.item():
                 records.args[k] = v.decode("utf-8")
        # I do not write everything, but I hope you understand.
        # And there you can do others things.
        return super(FooFormatter, self).format(record)
```

It's all!) Many thanks to my curator who helped.